# Dose Firebase support raspberry pi ? (have no google play service device)

Tags: firebase, raspberry-pi3

Does Firebase support raspberry pi ?
( pi have no google play service )
or any suggestion for this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase is a suite of products. Some of those are focused on native mobile (iOS and Android) developers, so won't work on a Pi. But others have a REST API, which allows you to use them from pretty much anywhere. An example of the latter is the Firebase Database. Read more about its REST API here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/start

Comment: Thank you for your reply,

If pi porting android OS, but not include google play service, 
does any suggest can help me ?

thanks a lot.